# What's a concise way to safely deal with implicitly unwrapped optionals in Swift?

Tags: swift

I was getting the infamous `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error on the `if let` line in this code:

```
var displayShelves: [Shelf] {
    get {
        if let shelves = rootShelf.childShelves as NSArray as? [Shelf] {
            return shelves
        }
        return []
}
```

The reason for this is that `rootShelf.childShelves` is an objective C class which is being imported into Swift as `var childShelves: NSMutableArray! { get set }`, so when I try to cast it to `[Shelf]`, it can equal `nil`.  How do I unwrap this concisely, without a lot of extra ifs or guards?  I could do the following:

```
var displayShelves: [Shelf] {
    get {
        if rootShelf.childShelves != nil {
            if let shelves = rootShelf.childShelves as NSArray as? [Shelf] {
                return shelves
            }
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

But that's the kind of code that optional chaining is supposed to prevent!  So, is there a Swift-y way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x` is of type `T!`, then `x as T` will act like a force-unwrap. You can use `x as T?` to continue treating it as Optional.

So in your case, you could do `return rootShelf.childShelves as NSArray? as? [Shelf] ?? []`.

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't crash when `rootShelf.childShelves` is `nil`:

```
var displayShelves: [Shelf] {
    get {
        if rootShelf.childShelves != nil, let shelves = rootShelf.childShelves as NSArray as? [Shelf] {
            return shelves
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure that the `,` operator is guaranteed to short-circuit like this.

Comment: Is this meant to be an actual answer to your own question or is this meant to be further information for your question? If the latter, please remove this answer and put the info in your question.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable self-answer to me.

Comment: @jtbandes I ask because of the last sentence.

Comment: It worked, but seemed like an abuse of the `,`.  @jtbandes had the better answer I was looking for!

Comment: FYI the comma here isn't really an operator, it's just part of the grammar for conditionals. It is guaranteed to short-circuit.